# When will Red Hat fully support & ship with python 2.7

Tags: centos, redhat, python

I realize there might not be a direct answer to this question, but I am wondering if there are  any communicated expectations of when this will happen or if anyone can comment on the challenges involved. I understand for instance yum is a major dependency on 2.6, but curious in what ways 2.7 is incompatible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RHEL 7 includes Python 2.7 and has been out for a while already.

Answer (score 4):

Not only is RHEL 7 supporting and shipping python 2.7, but from RHEL 6.4 and onwards python 2.7 is available through "Software collections".

From [Red Hat Software Collections 1.0 product documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/1/html/1.0_Release_Notes/chap-RHSCL.html#sect-RHSCL-Compatibility):

> With the notable exception of Node.js, all Red Hat Software
>   Collections components are fully supported under Red Hat Enterprise
>   Linux Subscription Level Agreements, are functionally complete, and
>   are intended for production use.

This set includes python 2.7 installed in parallel with the version provided by default, installed under `/opt`.

There are more software in there worth noting like PostgreSQL 9.2 and Perl 5.16.3.

Comment: Yep, they're all there too. But for a greenfield project I'd sooner go with RHEL 7 over RHEL 6 + SCL for the longer lifetime and so that messing with SCL isn't necessary. It can be quite a pain to work with.

Comment: Yes I agree there is some learning curve, but having been around for a while is not only a bad thing for an OS either, considering how many bug fixes are already merged in there, and the amount of documented support issues on the Internet and in the Red Hat Customer portal. Besides, RHEL have really long life cycles. That said, I'd consider RHEL 7 too, you have to learn systemd at some point.

Comment: I learned systemd years ago :)